# segfault when setting bool possible?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, boolean

I have a binary tree, whose nodes are defined as

```
typedef unsigned long ul;
struct Fibonacci_node{
    ul number;                              
    int n;                                 
    bool isLeaf;                            
    Fibonacci_node * left;
    Fibonacci_node * right;
  };
```

I'd like to set `isLeaf` each insertion, so that I could easily get the total number of leafs eventually. The insertion method is made up of a public method, *insert*, that calls the private recursive method *insertR*.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fibonacci_tree{
    private:
        struct Fibonacci_node{
        ul number;                              // store the n-th fibonacci number
        int n;                                  // fibonacci number to compute
        bool isLeaf;                            // true if the node is leaf
        Fibonacci_node * left;
        Fibonacci_node * right;
      };



        /* definition of the root of the binary tree */
        Fibonacci_node * root;

        /* class private methods (recursively defined) */
        ul fibonacci(int n){
        /* BASE CASE */
        if (n == 0) { return 1; }
        if (n == 1) { return 1; }

        /* call the function recursively */
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
      };

      Fibonacci_node * insertR(int n, Fibonacci_node * node){
        if (!node) {
        /* if pointer is null create a new node */

        Fibonacci_node * tmp = new Fibonacci_node;
        tmp->n = n;
        tmp->number = fibonacci(tmp->n);
        tmp->left = tmp->right = 0;
        tmp->isLeaf = 0;

        /* update the pointer and return it */
        node = tmp;

        /* BASE CASE */
        if (n == 0) {
          node->isLeaf = 1;
          return node;
        }
        if (n == 1) {
          node->isLeaf = 1;
          return node;
        }
      }

      /* call the function recursively */
      node->left = insertR(n - 1, node->left);
      node->right = insertR(n - 2, node->right);

      return node;
    };

  public:
    Fibonacci_tree(){
      root = 0;
    }
    ~Fibonacci_tree(){}

    /* class public methods (they include private methods recursively defined)*/
    void insert(int n){

      /* first, create initial node and compute fibonacci for the root */
      Fibonacci_node * tmp = new Fibonacci_node;
      tmp->n = n;
      tmp->number = fibonacci(n);
      tmp->isLeaf = false;
      //getNo(tmp);

      /* make root point to the first element of the tree */
      root = tmp;

      /* then call the recursive function */
      root = insertR(n, root);
    };
};
/* END OF CLASS DECLARATION */


/* main program to check the class */
int main(void) {
  int n = 3;

  /* instantiate a Fibonacci tree */
  Fibonacci_tree fib_series;
  /* fill the tree */
  fib_series.insert(n);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run my executable, I get

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I printed several comments and I noted that the error seems appear immediately after before I assign "false" to the boolean. So, I'm assuming that the assignment gets wrong but it's the first time I get segmentation fault in such a situation.

I also think that because so far I haven't had any problem but this, and it started when I introduced this variable in the class definition.

Could it be possible to get segmentation fault because of this, or I may have a problem elsewhere that I haven't noted yet?

I'd like to completely debug it by myself, but my debugging skills still sucks a bit. Any feedback is therefore really appreciated.

Comment: where is this tmp coming from?

Comment: You might think you are setting isLeaf but if tmp which is a pointer points not to an instance of Fibonacci_node but to some random memory you are doing some very nasty things overwritting stuff you shouldn't, So, no, setting a bool cant cause segfault, but randomly writting memory probably in the long run can.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: Have you asked for the value of `tmp` under the debugger: is it `nullptr`, in the stack, in the heap?

Comment: Have you read anything else than the "rubber duck" part in [this link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) ?

Comment: @SergeyA I edited the code, hope it's clear now.

Comment: @MichaelWalz could it be better? I'm pretty new here, so my apologies.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna Your code example is still far from a [MCVE]. Read up the link again.

Comment: @MichaelWals, actually yes. I read it thoroughly but unfortunately I cannot master my skills as debugger in less than one month. I'm trying to use the debugger inside Xcode, I'm reading carefully all the error and warnings when I use -Wall and -Wextra. I'm printing lots on information to understand where I get stuck and I draw a lot of trees. I also know that StackOverflow doesn't provide me a debugging service, but since I don't know if such behaviour could be possible a priori I just asked.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna we need a [MCVE]. What you have provided is Minimal, but not complete nor verifiable. You need to post an example as small as possible that produces the segfault. Without that all we can say is: _`tmp` gets corrupted for some reason_.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna it's better, but I still cannoot copy/paste the code in one piece. Especially the `fibonacci` function is missing.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna sigh... post __the whole code__ `deleteR` is missing.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, the problem is not that function. I exactly copy-pasted my own code, compiled and got segfault.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna `deleteR` is still missing in the code you posted, but I was able to fint the problem anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is here:

```
 /* call the function recursively */
    node->left = insertR(n - 1, node->left);
```

at that point `node->left` is not yet initialized, you pass that non inizialized value recursively to `insertR`, where you check if it's `NULL`, as it is non inizialized it is most likely non null, and then you dereference it again here: `node->left = insertR(n - 1, node->left);`. Dereferencing a non initialized pointer is undefined behaviour.

Actually you simply forgot to initialize `left`and `right` to 0 here:

```
/* first, create initial node and compute fibonacci for the root */
Fibonacci_node * tmp = new Fibonacci_node;
tmp->n = n;
tmp->number = fibonacci(n);
tmp->isLeaf = false;
tmp->left = tmp->right = 0;    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< you forgot this.
//getNo(tmp);
```

As you are writing in C++ why don't you write a constructor for `Fibonacci_node` where all the initialisation could be done in one place ?

`tmp->isLeaf = false;` causing a segfault on your computer is just a consequence of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Aah, I thought I initialised the root pointers inside the constructor but when I assign root to point to tmp, that node has no initialisation for its pointers. Is that my leak? I'm going to consider to add this inside the class constructor, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, as I pointed out in the answer you simply forgot to initialize `left` and `right`. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

If `tmp` is not a valid pointer (NULL, something that has been freed, something that has gone out of scope, or something that has not been allocated properly in the first place), this is likely the cause.

Comment: This belong to a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'd delete this "answer" before it gets downvoted more. It's not (yet) my downvote.

Comment: I disagree.  This is the answer on the question as I read it.

Comment: The question was whether or not the segfault was possible. "Yes." is too short for an answer so I went one further and explained some possible causes (at least as much as possible given the lack of information provided in the question). While it might not be a good answer (due to the lack of important information in the question which others already commented on), I don't see how it's not an answer.

Comment: @Muzer I edited my post and I show how I create my pointer to a new node. I really don't understand, because when I pass some value to other variables (e.g. _n_) I don't get any problem.